# Microsoft Web installer can't find Azure SDK 2.7 for Vs2015

Tags: azure

I'm trying to install the azure 2.7 for vs 2015 from this [Link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/announcing-the-azure-sdk-2-7-for-net/).

But when I run the installer it automatically shows the latest version (2.9), i've tried to use Microsoft Web installer but it do not shows the version 2.7.

Is there any way to install that specific version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the Web Platform Installer and download the different parts that make up the [Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET - 2.7](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-sdk-dotnet-release-notes-2_7/) here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178